# C++ take numbers from string and make calculation

Tags: c++, string, count, numbers

I have to write a program that take numbers from string and then make the sum of these numbers.

example: string test="12,20,7";  result=50

Can someone help me? ty

```
 string stringNumber="12,20,7";   
 vector<int> test;
 vector<int> position;
string help;
int br=0;
int a;
for(int x=0; x<stringNumber.length(); x++)
{
    if(stringNumber.at(x) !=';'){          //save numbers
        help=stringNumber.at(x);
        istringstream istr(help);
        istr>>a;
        test.push_back(a);
        br++;
    }
    if(stringNumber.at(x) ==';'){     //save position of ","
        position.push_back(br);
        br++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: 12 + 20 + 7 != 50 ... ?

Comment: Your string has commas but your code tests for semi-colons. Obviously it will help if you fix that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible alternative that does not need saving the numbers and the positions of separators. It also does not use `std::stringstream`, although it could be easily rewritten to use it instead of `std::atoi()`. Finally, you can pass the delimiter you prefer as a second argument to `compute_sum`, defaulting to `","`:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int compute_sum(std::string const& s, std::string const& delim = ",")
{
    int sum = 0;
    auto pos = s.find(delim);
    decltype(pos) start = 0;
    while (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        auto sub = s.substr(start, pos - start);
        sum += std::atoi(sub.c_str());

        start = pos + 1;
        pos = s.find(delim, start);
    }

    if (start != pos + 1)
    {
        auto sub = s.substr(start);
        sum += std::atoi(sub.c_str());
    }

    return sum;
}
```

This is how you would use it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << compute_sum("12,20,7");
}
```

And here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3SRz1U%24134).

Comment: @Nik: You're welcome. If this solves your problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: I have another problem, how to store each number in vector? I only managed to save each number separately...

Comment: @Nik: That is another question. Anyway, take the result of `std::atoi(sub.c_str());` from the above code and push it into a vector before adding it to `sum`